# Диспетчер задач Пользователи

Tags: c#

Как в c# получить список пользователей работающих сейчас на компьютере с их состоянием (активен, отключен)

Comment: Скорее всего WMI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаете запрос к WMI, и дальше проходите по нужным свойствам:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher users = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_Account");
foreach (var u in users.Get())
{
    string login = u.Properties["Caption"].Value.ToString();
    string name = u.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
    string status = u.Properties["Status"].Value.ToString();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно выполнить запрос к WMI

```
var usersSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount");
var users = usersSearcher.Get();
```

Ну и копать в эту сторону. (WMI)